# Java about 100 parallel threads, memory management

Tags: java, memory-management, multithreading, scheduling

I am writing an optimazation algorithm which creates about 100 threads. Currently, I start them all at one time (for-loop) and after that I tell every thread that it should join().

My problem is now that each thread uses to much memory so the heap space exception won't take long. I want some kind of scheduling but don't know how to implement it.

I have something like this in mind: start 10 threads and every time one of these finishes start a new one. So that there are allways running 10 threads at a time until no thread is left.

Has someone an idea or knows how to realize something like this?

Thank you very much and regards from Cologne

Marco

Comment: If you're interested in java and concurrency I highly recommend this book: http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the number of cores in the machine you will be using. Performance will be best if the number of threads you normally have running equals the number of cores. As KLE says, use a thread pool.

Comment: I currently run 2 a time cause its a Core2Duo from Intel. Performance looks good...

Comment: this might be true if you are fully CPU-bound, but if there are any blocking operations (e.g. IO, sleeping, certain types of locking) then you usually want more threads than cores in order to keep the cores fully utilised.

Answer (score 19):

Use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)) with an appropriate maximum pool size.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to get you started. First, what you'll need to import:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

And then what you need to put inside your method:

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(final Task task: tasks) { 
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    while(!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for tasks to shutdown");
    }
```

Some notes about the above:

- You'll need to implement your own
  Task class that actually implements
  your algorithm
- The task class doesn't have to just
  have an execute method (in fact, if
  it has that signature, you could just
  get your task to implement Runnable
  and avoid the anonymous inner class)
- You'll need to make sure that
  everything that you use is properly
  synchronised. The classes in
  `java.util.concurrent.atomic` are
  quite good if you have shared state
  you need to update (e.g. if you want
  to have a counter for how many tasks
  you've processed).
- You typically only want as many
  threads executing as there are cores
  / cpus on your machine. Often
  performance often goes up when
  numbers of threads goes down.
  Normally you only use more threads if
  your tasks spend a lot of time
  blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting a new Thread to do a new task, you are much better off to:

- have a queue of tasks to execute (instead of threads to run)
- **use a smaller pool of threads** (as mentionned by Michael) **to process these tasks**.

The difference in speed and memory is huge, because you don't have to start and stop a thread for each task.

The package java.util.concurrent explains everything about this.
A book would be easier to read though :-(